# JUnit parameter in @Rule @Before and @After

Tags: java, junit, junit4, citrus-framework

I need an advice on how the following snippet can be implemented in all test methods.

```
@Test 
public void testCatalogItemUpdate() {
    String correlationId = getCorrelation();
    try {
        parallel().actions( 
         //use correlationId
         //invoke test scenario
         //assert results
    );

    } finally {
        print(correlationId);
    }
}
```

I read about @Rule and @Before and @After annotations.

Comment: will the correlationid be always same? if not from where will it come from?

Comment: when if your test supposed to run ? before ? after ? in the middle ?

Comment: is this a test, a preparation for each test or something to clean up after your test?

Comment: Where are the asserts? Currently it is just a run. Without asserts, it is not a test.

Comment: I tried to modify code example in order to answer all questions from above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not comment as i don't have enough points so i tried to give the solution with my understanding. So please clarify one thing that you added the comments with in parameter section like below

```
parallel().action(/*test scenario and assert results are here*/);
```

Any specific reason for it?

Here is the code snippet. Please check if it helps

```
private String correlationId;
@Before
public void beforeEachTest(){
    correlationId = getCorrelation();
    parallel().actions(correlationId);
}

@Test
public void testCatalogItemUpdate(){
    //Execute test scenario using correlationId
    //Assert results
}

@After
public void afterEachTest(){
    print(correlationId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for post. I believe I will check this

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform those actions either at the beginning of test or at the end of it, you may try to use those BeforeTest or AfterTest components. I'm not sure if you can call Citrus tests within those sections, but you can try. Here is an example of usage of before test (you need to add it to citrus-context file):

```
<citrus:before-test id="defaultBeforeTest">
    <citrus:actions>
        <citrus-test:java class="<class path and class name to be here" >
            <citrus-test:method name="<method name>" >
                <citrus-test:argument>${<if any variable should be passed>}</citrus-test:argument>
                <citrus-test:argument>1</citrus-test:argument>
            </citrus-test:method>
        </citrus-test:java>
        <!-- access to Citrus method  -->
        <citrus-test:purge-channel>
            <citrus-test:channel name="<server_name>.inbound"/>
        </citrus-test:purge-channel>
    </citrus:actions>
</citrus:before-test>
```

You may also look at the Templates in Citrus (http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/templates.html), especially if you need to run that code in the middle of your test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BeforeTestSupport classes in Citrus

You should extend the BeforeTestSupport classes and add these to the Spring application context:

```
public class MyBeforeTest extends TestDesignerBeforeTestSupport {
    @Override
    public void beforeTest(TestDesigner designer) {
        designer.echo("This action should be executed before suite");
    }
}

<bean id="myBeforeTest" class="my.company.citrus.MyBeforeTest"/>
```

The beforeTest method is provided with the test designer instance which is then capable to receive the Java DSL calls in Citrus. Of course you can also use the test runner alternative with respective base TestRunnerBeforeTestSupport class.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will also take a look on those.Currently "@Before" and "@After" I find it more clean solution